# How can I use survival analysis with multi-state model to look at a progressive events (gentrification stages)?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, survival

I'm working examining the effect of a particular anti-gentrification policy in Berlin. I want to use a survival analysis to see if the amount of time it takes any area to progress to the next stage of gentrification out of five stages (ungentrified through gentrified), but a normal regression doesn't work here because some areas might stop gentrifying altogether, and thus have 0 or NA for the time to the next stage. I've tried using R's `survival` and `mstate` packages but haven't had much luck finding relevant literature for this sort of analysis, and I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how best to go about this.

For some further context, here's some of the dataset I'm using, where `gcode` is the final status in 2019, and `tg0`:`tg5` is the time it takes to get from stage 0 to 1, 1 to 2, and so on. As you can see, the `0.000` places represent censored data where an area never reached the next stage.

```
> head(data, n=20)
    RAUMID gcode   tg0    tg1   tg2   tg3   tg4   tg5
1  1011101     4 2.001  1.999 2.001 4.000 0.000    NA
2  1011102     5 0.999  4.000 4.000 2.001 1.999 5.002
3  1011103     2 0.999 12.000 0.000 0.000 0.000    NA
4  1011104     4 0.999  6.001 1.999 4.000 0.000    NA
5  1011105     4 0.999  4.000 2.001 9.999 0.000    NA
6  1011201     4 0.999  6.001 1.999 6.001 0.000    NA
7  1011202     4 0.999  2.001 1.999 6.001 0.000    NA
8  1011203     4 0.999  4.000 2.001 4.000 0.000    NA
9  1011204     4 0.999  6.001 1.999 2.001 0.000    NA
10 1011301     2 0.999 12.000 0.000 0.000 0.000    NA
11 1011302     1 0.999  0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000    NA
12 1011303     5 0.999  2.001 1.999 2.001 4.000 7.001
13 1011304     2 0.000  0.999 0.000 0.000 0.000    NA
14 1011305     4 0.999  8.000 6.001 1.999 0.000    NA
15 1011306     2 0.000  0.999 0.000 0.000 0.000    NA
16 1011401     2 2.001  1.999 0.000 0.000 0.000    NA
17 1011402     1 2.001  0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000    NA
18 1022101     4 0.000  0.999 4.000 4.000 0.000    NA
19 1022102     4 0.000  0.999 4.000 4.000 0.000    NA
20 1022103     2 0.000 11.001 0.000 0.000 0.000    NA
```

Creating dummy variables for whether an area has been censored or whether it was treated during the period when it transitioned from one stage to another has been no problem, but actually using survival analysis for this type of problem has been really tricky.

**Edit**: for some additional context, here is a sample of data from which I calculated `tg0` through `tg5`:

To provide some further context, stage 0 means not (yet) gentrifiable, and is calculated based on an area being above the 70th percentile in average sale prices for residential properties. While I went back and forth on whether these areas should simply be eliminated from the dataset entirely before continued categorization, I decided to include them as, theoretically, an area could be initially ungentrifiable but then decrease in value sufficiently over the course of 10 years to be gentrifiable.

```
> head(data, n=20)
    RAUMID   gcode0yr   gcode1yr   gcode2yr   gcode3yr   gcode4yr   gcode5yr
1  1011101 2002-12-31 2004-12-31 2006-12-31 2008-12-31 2012-12-31       <NA>
2  1011102 2001-12-31 2002-12-31 2006-12-31 2010-12-31 2012-12-31 2014-12-31
3  1011103 2001-12-31 2002-12-31 2014-12-31       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
4  1011104 2001-12-31 2002-12-31 2008-12-31 2010-12-31 2014-12-31       <NA>
5  1011105 2001-12-31 2002-12-31 2006-12-31 2008-12-31 2018-12-31       <NA>
6  1011201 2001-12-31 2002-12-31 2008-12-31 2010-12-31 2016-12-31       <NA>
7  1011202 2001-12-31 2002-12-31 2004-12-31 2006-12-31 2012-12-31       <NA>
8  1011203 2001-12-31 2002-12-31 2006-12-31 2008-12-31 2012-12-31       <NA>
9  1011204 2001-12-31 2002-12-31 2008-12-31 2010-12-31 2012-12-31       <NA>
10 1011301 2001-12-31 2002-12-31 2014-12-31       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
11 1011302 2001-12-31 2002-12-31       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
12 1011303 2001-12-31 2002-12-31 2004-12-31 2006-12-31 2008-12-31 2012-12-31
13 1011304       <NA> 2001-12-31 2002-12-31       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
14 1011305 2001-12-31 2002-12-31 2010-12-31 2016-12-31 2018-12-31       <NA>
15 1011306       <NA> 2001-12-31 2002-12-31       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
16 1011401 2002-12-31 2004-12-31 2006-12-31       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
17 1011402 2002-12-31 2004-12-31       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
18 1022101       <NA> 2001-12-31 2002-12-31 2006-12-31 2010-12-31       <NA>
19 1022102       <NA> 2001-12-31 2002-12-31 2006-12-31 2010-12-31       <NA>
20 1022103       <NA> 2001-12-31 2012-12-31       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

Another edit: Here is the outcome of my data wrangling:

```
 dataL %>% group_by(RAUMID) %>% head(n=10)
# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   RAUMID [10]
    RAUMID startTime endTime event treatment_starttime treatedduring
     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>               <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 1011101      4       6.00 tg2                  NA               0
 2 1011102      2.00    6.00 tg2                  NA               0
 3 1011103      2.00   14.0  tg2                  18.0             0
 4 1011104      2.00    8    tg2                  NA               0
 5 1011105      2.00    6.00 tg2                  NA               0
 6 1011201      2.00    8    tg2                  NA               0
 7 1011202      2.00    4    tg2                  NA               0
 8 1011203      2.00    6.00 tg2                  NA               0
 9 1011204      2.00    8    tg2                  NA               0
10 1011301      2.00   14.0  tg2                  NA               0
> dataL %>% group_by(RAUMID) %>% filter(treatedduring == 1) %>%  head(n=10)
# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   RAUMID [10]
    RAUMID startTime endTime event treatment_starttime treatedduring
     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>               <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 2020204     0.999    6.00 tg2                 2.18              1
 2 2020206     0.999    2.00 tg2                -5.43              1
 3 2030401     0.999    4    tg2                -5.43              1
 4 2050802     4        6.00 tg2                -1.71              1
 5 3040614     2.00    19.0  cens               -0.791             1
 6 3050925     2.00    19.0  cens               16.9               1
 7 3061126     0.999   19.0  cens               -1.74              1
 8 3061131     4       19.0  cens               -3.78              1
 9 3061227     0.999   19.0  cens               -0.153             1
10 3061332     2.00    19.0  cens               13.5               1
```

Comment: Is this always a progression upward from `tg0` through `tg5`, or can there be a movement in the anti-gentrification direction (e.g., from `tg2` back to `tg1`)?

Comment: There is only progression upward, so no anti-gentrification direction :)

Comment: Your last "outcome of data wrangling" only seems to show 1 row per `RAUMID`. I can't tell if that's an issue with the wrangling itself or the way the data are displayed. If you use standard multi-state survival modeling, you need at least 1 row per time epoch within each `tg` state for each `RAUMID`. If you use discrete-time survival analysis, you need 1 row per year (if that's your time scale) per `RAUMID`. Be careful not to throw away useful data.

Comment: Yes sorry, to be clear this was just displaying rows not grouped by `RAUMID` — in my dataframe I have one row for each area for each epoch for each gentrification state, with the final one either being `tg5` or `cens`. Not sure why it didn't group by `RAUMID` here — it does so when I click the column while in `view(dataL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [multi-state vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf) for the R survival package sets out how to approach this type of problem; your situation with a set of sequential, uni-directional possible transitions is illustrated in the top right panel of Figure 1 of the vignette. So in principle your situation can be handled with a survival model.

The main problems here are: (1) formatting the data correctly, (2) formulating the model appropriately and (3) geting a useful result even if you do all that. Item (3) can't really be predicted in advance. Here's what you need to watch out for in Items (1) and (2).

The main task for Item (1) is to convert these wide-form data into long-form data, with each row representing a particular defined time period for a single `RAUMID`. Each row then specifies the  `RAUMID`, a start time, a stop time, any covariate values in place during the period (in particular, was the anti-gentrification policy in place) and whether there was a change of state (event) at the end of the period.

That `(startTime,stopTime,event)` formulation requires two additional steps starting from your data. First, the times you currently show are for the *durations* within each state. You probably should convert those all to *time elapsed since study start* (taken to be `time = 0`).

Second, you need to specify a categorical variable that represents an `event`, a change in state in your situation. With the `survival` package the reference level of that variable needs to represent censoring, or no change in state at `stopTime`. As there are no transitions into `tg0` you don't need to include a level for that, but you would need to specify categories for `tg1`, `tg2`, `tg3`, `tg4`, and `tg5`. For each `(startTime, stopTime, event)`, if there is a change of state at `stopTime` you set the `event` variable to the corresponding new category. That format also allows for a change in covariate values over time; if the time period in question didn't end with an event change, the `event` category is listed as the reference level representing censoring. If I'm interpreting your data display correctly, the first row of your data would be changed into multiple rows as follows:

| RAUMID | startTime | stopTime | event | policy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1011101 | 0 | 2.001 | tg1 | p? |
| 1011101 | 2.001 | 4.000 | tg2 | p? |
| 1011101 | 4.000 | 6.001 | tg3 | p? |
| 1011101 | 6.001 | 10.001 | tg4 | p? |
| 1011101 | 10.001 | t? | cens | p? |

The `t?` in the last `stopTime` should be replaced by the time elapsed between `time = 0` and the last follow-up, when the `RAUM` was still in state `tg4`. The `policy` value, shown as `p?` above, represents the policy in place during that time interval. You append whatever other covariate values held during each time period within the `RAUM` as additional columns. If a new policy comes into play at time $T_p$ after `time = 0`, set a `stopTime` equal to $T_p$ and a censoring `event` for all affected `RAUMID` (unless there was also an event change at that time) and start a new data row with `startTime` of $T_p$.

Your sample data indicate a couple of things that you'll need to clarify. First, some `RAUMID` show values for `tg5`, which I interpret to mean time spent in `tg5`. If there is no transition possible out of `tg5` it's not clear what that's intended to represent. Also, some `RAUMID` show values of 0 for the time in state `tg0`. Presumably those are cases in which the first observed state was `tg1`. If that's the case, you would specify the initial state with an `istate` argument ; see page 8 of the multi-state vignette.

The main [survival package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/survival.pdf) provides guidance on tools available to help with this type of data formatting, and in particular the `survcheck()` function that helps identify the errors that are almost inevitable in practice. Once the data are in that format, the multi-state vignette shows how to generate curves showing things like the probability in each state as a function of time

For Item (2), you presumably want to see if policy changes affected the rate of transitions. You then need to apply your knowledge of the subject matter, in particular: do you expect the change in policy to affect all transitions similarly, or might it have different effects on different transitions? Section 3.4.2 of the main `survival` vignette illustrates how you can allow for either common or different effects of covariates on each transition.

As the data are only collected annually, you will probably be better off approaching this as a discrete-time survival analysis. That can be done as an appropriately formatted logistic regression. John Willett has a [website](http://gseacademic.harvard.edu/%7Ewilletjo/dsta.htm) with several references to publications with his colleagues, in particular Judith Singer, showing how this can be done with logistic regression. Paul Allison wrote a characteristically clear [review in 1982](http://www.jstor.org/stable/270718?origin=JSTOR-pdf) discussing the principles and describing both logistic regression and complementary log-log modeling approaches. Tutz and Schmid have a more recent [book-length treatment](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319281568) with R code, including how to use tools provided by the [discSurv](https://cran.r-project.org/package=discSurv) package.

One possibility would be to format your data with one row per `RAUMID` per year, including (along with other covariates) the starting `tg` state as a categorical predictor, whether the `policy` was in effect that year, and a 0/1 outcome variable for no transition versus transition to next `tg` state that year. Logistic regression then would provide coefficients representing the effects of starting `tg` state and of `policy` on the log-odds of transition to the next state. You could include an interaction term between `tg` and `policy` in the model to see whether the `policy` has different associations with transitions depending on the `tg` state.

Finally, from comments it seems that your assignments to `tg` states is based on a categorization process done every 2 years. That has two potential implications. For one, if you only do the categorization every 2 years, you might need to re-cast your data format into 2-year bins. For another, you might consider whether you would be better off primarily modeling a continuous measure of the gentrification process, then perhaps translating the results with the continuous measure into your categorization.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer! Regarding a few of your questions and concerns, I have already formatted the data for a separate panel model into long format, so adding the start and stop times and events shouldn't be too much trouble. Additionally, the `tg5` variable represents the time spent in stage 4 before reaching stage 5. You are correct regarding the areas that spent 0 time in stage 0; I'll look into the `instate` argument for that. I am curious if you could elaborate on discrete-time survival analysis; I'm not at all familiar with this concept. Regardless, thank you again!!

Comment: @cschwab98 your explanation for `tg5` is hard to reconcile with the second data row showing values for all of `tg0` through `tg5`. I thought that the value of 1.999 for `tg4` in that row represented the time in `tg4` before entry into `tg5`. Otherwise, do the values for `tg0` then mean the time spent in some previous undefined state before entering `tg0`? I'll add a bit on discrete-time analysis later.

Comment: Hi @EdM, looking back at my data generation script, I now realize why you were confused, and what I had been overlooking; you are entirely correct in your confusion, and I think I should drop the `tg5` variable. It was created by finding the difference in time between the start of stage 5 gentrification and the end of the study in 2020. I don't think this is relevant data for this analysis (it's been a feverish few weeks working on this, so sorry for troubling you with this oversight).

Comment: In terms of dealing with `istate`, I think it makes the most sense to not even examine `tg0`, as it isn't a particularly relevant variable to my analysis, now that I think about it.

Comment: @cschwab98 you need to have some starting state from which to make the transition to `tg1`, so if you don't define it the system will make one up anyway. The discrete-time analysis might simplify this: for a logistic regression each year, you include the starting state for each `RAUM` as a covariate; whether you transit to the next state is the "event" for an outcome of 1; otherwise, the outcome for that year is 0. (That might need a work-around if you can have 2 transitions in a single year.) With that format, starting a `RAUM` at a state higher than `tg0` is no problem.

Comment: That makes sense! what I was thinking in my last comment is that it might make sense to only look at `tg1` through `tg4`, as `tg0` would represent the time from when an area was ungentrifiable to when it was pre-gentrification state, a kind of urban degeneration (not a great word choice, but regardless) that I'm not interested in researching

Comment: In regards to a discrete-time analysis and long format generally, I think a discrete time analysis would make sense, as I filters areas through the categorization system every two years, so either an area will be re-categorized or not at each year. Interesting!

Comment: Sorry to keep bombarding you with questions, but after finally pulling together the data sufficiently to use it, I was also wondering whether there should be different categories of censoring, e.g. censored post stage 1 versus censored post stage 3. I've also updated the question with the results of my data wrangling.

Comment: @cschwab98 see the details added to the end of the answer. With respect to the censoring indicator, censoring just means you haven't yet seen a transition to the _next_ state, whatever that next state is. Your data and model keep track of the current state, so you don't need to have different censoring indicators. Censoring while in `tg2` will be interpreted when estimating the characteristics of transition to `tg3`; the same censoring indicator for a `RAUMID` in `tg4` will be interpreted correctly when estimating the characteristics of transition to `tg5`.